# How we can find currentDate is in date range or not

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-comparison

I get three dates: *From date*, *To date* and *current date*.

I want to find whether current date is in between From and To dates. If current date is in between these two dates then I want to create two new From and To dates.

**Example:**

- From Date = 15 march
- To Date = 25 march
- current date = 21 march

Expected result should be:

1. From Date= 15 march,  To Date=21 march
2. From date= 21 march,  To Date=25 march

To implement this logic I want to check my current date status whether it's in middle of date range or it's before or after.

Comment: These dates, are they Strings or Dates? In case they are already of class Date, you could use the methods before() and after()

Comment: If you are using java.util.Date. You can also use compareTo.

Comment: its in Date format

Comment: Be careful depending on what a date range represents.  Is it OK if `21 March` is a member of both date ranges? Do ranges have to be non-overlapping?  You may need to rethink date range so that it is half-open, i.e. the ending date is not part of the range.  This is a common issue you must deal with working with ranges of any kind.

Comment: Tip: [`org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html)

Answer (score 1):

You said in the comments that your inputs are *"in date format"*, but that's a very vague description, because, technically speaking, [`Date` objects don't have a format](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

If your inputs are instances of `java.util.Date`, then just use the [methods `before`, `after` and `equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#method_summary) to compare the dates.

If you're using Java 8, the [`java.time` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is a much better choice. You can either use a `java.time.LocalDate` or even a `java.time.MonthDay`, if you don't care about the year.

Both classes have comparison methods: `isAfter`, `isBefore` and `equals`, and a `now()` method to get the current date.
With those, you have all the tools to implement your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();

    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateString1 = "2017-02-15";
    String dateString2 = "2015-03-12";
    String dateString3 = "2016-07-19";
    Date date1 = null,date2=null,date3=null;

    try {
        date1 = sdf.parse(dateString1);
        date2 = sdf.parse(dateString2);
        date3 = sdf.parse(dateString3);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    dates.add(date1);
    dates.add(date2);
    dates.add(date3);

    Collections.sort(dates, new Comparator<Date>() {
        public int compare(Date d1, Date d2) {
            return d1.compareTo(d2);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: For sure `java.time` it's a better approach